# WebRTC video constraints not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, webrtc

I'm trying to get a lower resolution from the webcam

```
navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, 
    video: {
        "mandatory" : {maxWidth : 320},
        "optional" : []
    }
}, function(stream) {
    videoElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}, function(error) {console.log(e)});
```

Everything works fine, but `videoElement.videoWidth` is still 640. This is the same whatever video constraints I specify. This is happening only in Firefox, in Chrome everything works fine.

Does anyone know why?

I also tried specifying `maxFrameRate`, but this is also ignored. I also tried without `optional` and with maxHeight too.

Comment: For which browser are you experiencing this issue?

Comment: This works on [this](https://simpl.info/getusermedia/constraints/) example, source [here](https://github.com/samdutton/simpl/blob/master/getusermedia/constraints/js/main.js). The only difference I see is that there is no `optional` defined, and that both `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` are defined.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent, indeed it seems a browser issue. It works on Chrome, but not on Firefox. I updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous bugs that are being handled in Firefox for it not supporting programable video framerate and resolution changes.

- [Allowing the framerate to be changed in the media constraints](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=846188)
- [Support runtime change of video resolution](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=912342)
- [Support plain numbers for the video resolution in the media constraints](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1006725)

You are supposedly able to set the constraints this way:

```
mediaConstraints = {
      "audio": true,
      "video": {
         width: {
             min: 320,
              max: 320
          },
          height: {
             min: 240,
              max: 240
          } }
    };
```

But I have never been able to get video resolution constraints to work it to work in Firefox through media constraints. I have had limited success with changing the default resolution in `about:config` in firefox.

These issues are known and I believe that numerous people are working on them to get them resolved.

Comment: The way you specified the constraints, as opposed to how I did it, does it make any difference? As far as I understood from your answer, it doesn't work either way.

Comment: It is ***SUPPOSED*** to according to what I have read about the implementation in Firefox but in my experience, it does not matter. I want to give FF the benefit of the doubt in that it could very well work in certain situations, but I have not found those situations yet.

Comment: On another note, I don't think it's good to specify both min and max for width and height because it could depend on the webcam aspect ratio.