# WebRTC Remote Video Resolution(s) too large

Tags: express, video-streaming, webrtc, p2p, videochat

I'm building a webrtc group video call, so far so good everything is working but the video resolution of the other users are too large. I've tried some solutions given on other questions like:

```
var video_constraints = {
mandatory: {
  maxHeight: 480,
  maxWidth: 640 
},
optional: []
};

webrtc.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
audio: true,
video: video_constraints
}, onsuccess);
```

But still no progress, instead my local video go blank. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Group Video Call</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
<!--============================  Main Starts 
 =============================================-->
<section>
  <div class="ui container">
    <div class="ui two column stackable grid">
      <div class="ui ten wide column">
                <div class="ui segment" id="segment">

    <!--=========================== local camera =============================================-->
                  <div class="ui six wide column" id="local">

                    <img id="local-image" class="ui large image">
                    <video id="local-video" class="ui large image" autoplay></video>

                  </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="video-actions">
        <button value="submit" class="outBtn">Make room public</button>
        <button value="submit" class="outBtn">Leave</button>
        <button value="submit" id="muteBtn">Mute</button>
        <button value="submit" class="outBtn">Kick</button>
      </div>

      <!--========================== reomte cameras 
       =============================================-->
      <div id="remote-videos" class="ui stackable grid">
        <div >
          <img class="ui centered small image">
        </div>
        <div >
          <img class="ui centered small image">
        </div>
        <div >
          <img class="ui centered small image">
        </div>
        <div >
          <img class="ui centered small image">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--======================== remote video template 
    =============================================-->
    <script id="remote-video-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
          <div id="{{ id }}" class="remote-img">
          </div>
        </script>

    <div class="clr"></div>
  </div>

</section>
</div>

<!--================================ scripts  
==============================================-->
<script src="../functions/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../functions/node_modules/handlebars/dist/handlebars.min.js "> 
</script>
<script src="../functions/node_modules/simplewebrtc/out/simplewebrtc-with- 
adapter.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="../functions/node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
 window.addEventListener('load', () => {

          // for Group Creator Video
          const localImageEl = $('#local-image');
          const localVideoEl = $('#local-video');

          // Joined Friends Videos
          const remoteVideoTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#remote-video- 
  template').html());
          const remoteVideosEl = $('#remote-videos');
          let remoteVideosCount = 0;

          let height = 200;
          let width = 200;

          // Hiding cameras until they are initialized
          localVideoEl.hide();

          // initial rules for form verification
          formEl.form({
            fields: {
              roomName: 'empty',
              username: 'empty',
            },
          });

          // create the webrtc connection
          const webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
            // the id dom element that will hold "our" video
            localVideoEl: 'local-video',
            // the id dom element that will hold remote videos
            remoteVideosEl: 'remote-videos',
            // for gaining video and voice access
            autoRequestMedia: true,
            debug: false,
            detectSpeakingEvents: true,
            autoAdjustMic: false,
          });

          // if (localCameraacess==1)
          webrtc.on('localStream', () => {
            localImageEl.hide();
            localVideoEl.show();

          });

          // adding remote videos
          webrtc.on('videoAdded', (video, peer) => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            const id = webrtc.getDomId(peer);
            const html = remoteVideoTemplate({ id });
            if (remoteVideosCount < 5){
                if (remoteVideosCount === 0) {
                  remoteVideosEl.html(html);
                } else {
                  remoteVideosEl.append(html);
                }

                $(`#${id}`).html(video);
                //$(`#${id} video`).addClass('ui image medium'); // for video 
  image to be responsive not good through
                remoteVideosCount += 1;
            }

          });

          // registeration of new chat room
          const createRoom = (roomName) => {

            console.info(`Creating new room: ${roomName}`);
            webrtc.createRoom(roomName, (err, name) => {
              formEl.form('clear');
              showChatRoom(name);
              postMessage(`${username} created chatroom`);
            });
          };

          // Join existing Chat Room
          const joinRoom = (roomName) => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.log(`Joining Room: ${roomName}`);
            webrtc.joinRoom(roomName);
            showChatRoom(roomName);
            postMessage(`${username} joined chatroom`);
          };

  });
```

I want to use a resolution of 320 x 240 on all remote video screens and also if i could get some code snippet on how to mute both VIDEO and AUDIO. And also leaving a connected peer. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebRTC firefox constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282385/webrtc-firefox-constraints)

Comment: Not all video devices support going as low as 320x240.  Why not indicate in your media constraints that you want 4:3 aspect ratio, enforce a low bitrate on the WebRTC side, and let the browser negotiate the scaling?  Is there some particular reason you want 320x240, or are you just trying to save bandwidth?

Comment: @Brad I could also go with other medium resolutions, the issue is i don't get any result when i use media constraint, just a blank screen

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers, but i found a fix from a question asked already:

[WebRTC video constraints not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159479/webrtc-video-constraints-not-working)

All i did was place the code above the 'window' function and it worked.
Still don't know if it will work on firefox.